# R - Scrape a page and display a list of items

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Please help me scrape the page,

https://support.sas.com/en/papers/proceedings-archive/sugi2005.html

to display the list of Paper names. See below what I have so far, but I do not know the class to use to achieve this. Thanks for helping!

```
pagetoread <- read_html("http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/toc.html",n=500)

get_paper_names <- function(html){
  html %>% 
    html_nodes('.?????') %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    str_trim() %>% 
    unlist()
}

get_paper_names(pagetoread)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do,

```
'https://support.sas.com/en/papers/proceedings-archive/sugi2005.html' %>% read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes('#par > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.par.parsys > div > div') %>% html_nodes('p') %>% html_nodes('cite') %>% 
  html_text()

 [1] "PROC FORMAT ? Not Just Another Pretty Face"                                                                                                                                           
  [2] "Efficiency Considerations Using the SAS System"                                                                                                                                       
  [3] "Through the Looking Glass: Two Windows into SAS"                                                                                                                                      
  [4] "Journeymen's Tools: Two Macros, ProgList and PutMvars, to Show Calling Sequence and Parameters of Routines"                                                                           
  [5] "SAS Batch Portal Data Collection and Real-Time Monitoring Application of SAS Batch Jobs"                                                                                              
  [6] "How to Get SAS Data into PowerPoint with SAS9"
```

First used JS path of highlighted class, then as the papers name are located under node `cite` which in turn are nested `p` nodes.
[image]

Comment: Thanks so very much! This works great! Could you please help me understand how you got to the html_nodes argument?

Comment: I added explanation hope it helps

Comment: `read_html() %>% html_elements('cite') %>% html_text()`

Comment: Yes, it does help. Thanks so much!